# R Shiny Interactive plot title for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to create Shiny App which is able to display interactive plot title (dependent on the choosen value for x axis)

Very simple example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

x <- as.numeric(1:1000000)
y <- as.numeric(1:1000000)
z <- as.numeric(1:1000000)
data <- data.frame(x,y, z)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(selectInput(inputId = "yaxis", 
                             label = "Y-axis",
                             choices = list("x","y","z"), 
                             selected = c("x")),
  dataTableOutput('tableId'),
                 plotOutput('plot1')),
  server = function(input, output) {    
    output$tableId = renderDataTable({
      datatable(data, options = list(pageLength = 10, lengthMenu=c(10,20,30)))
    })
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({
      filtered_data <- data[input$tableId_rows_all, ]
      ggplot(data=filtered_data, aes_string(x="x",y=input$yaxis)) + geom_line()  
    })
  }
)
```

I have tried this code:

```
ggtitle("Line plot of x vs",input$yaxis)
```

It was not working, plot has not been displayed, giving me an Error:

```
Warning: Error in ggtitle: unused argument (input$yaxis)
```

**[IMPORTANT]**

using `ggtitle(input$yaxis)` gives me an interactive title, however i need to build up a sentence (like: **Line plot of x vs** `input$yaxis`), in which the reactive argument (`input$yaxis`) is a part of it!

Thanks for any help!

Cheers

Comment: Use `ggtitle(paste("Line plot of x vs", input$yaxis))`?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Perhaps the question seemed easy, but the point of S.O. is to *help* folks, including folks who are new.  The OP did a good job explaining the question and formatting it.  S/He clearly put some effort before putting the question up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change:

```
ggtitle("Line plot of x vs",input$yaxis)
```

To

```
ggtitle(paste("Line plot of x vs",input$yaxis))
```

As the error suggests, you have too many arguments passed to the `ggtitle` function, `paste` will create a single character out of your two inputs, with a space in between. You can vary the separation between the two with `sep =`.